# Column filtering according to type in a loop

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am doing column filtering by using [this example](https://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/dateRange.html) as reference  and this is what I am doing and it's working fine.

I have multiple columns so how can  we implement it by using loop  here?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
         var table;
         // DataTable               
         table = $('#example').dataTable({
             "processing": true,
             stateSave: true,
             "deferRender": true, // to make the search fast         

             "dom": 'C<"clear">Rfltipr', // for column Re-odering and column visibilty.  

             "ajax": {
                 "url": "/my/example.so",
                 "type": "GET"
             },
             "columns": [{
                 "title": "name",
                 "data": "name",
                 "name": "name"
             }, {
                 "title": "addeddate",
                 "data": "addeddate",
                 "name": "added date"
             }]
         });
         table.columnFilter({
                 sPlaceHolder: "head:before",
                 aoColumns: [{
                         type: "text"
                     }, {
                         type: "date-range",
                         bRegex: true,
                         bSmart: true
                     }
                 }
             ]
         }); 

         $.datepicker.regional[""].dateFormat = 'yy-mm-dd';
         $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['']);
```

Moreover, here I need to write `<th>` tags also for all columns which is not good in case of multiple columns AS WELL.                                                                                        // second way to do it which is not suitable to do for date column   Setup - add a text input to each  cell

```
var noofcolumn= $('#example thead th').length;
                    colmn="";

                    for(i=0; i<noofcolumn; i++)
                    {
                    var title = $('#example thead th').eq( i ).text();
                    colmn+='<th><input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" /></th>';
                    }
                    $('#example tfoot').html( colmn );


                 // Apply the search

                    table.columns().every( function ()
                            {
                    $('input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
                        table
                            .column( $(this).parent().index()+':visible' )
                            .search( this.value )
                            .draw();

                    } );

        });
```

Comment: You can produce an array of objects in a loop, store it in a variable and use it as a parameter to `columns` and `aoColumns` options.

Comment: can you provide an example  I am very new for javascripts?

Comment: Is number of columns predetermined or dynamic? If pre-determined, then you don't need a loop, just add more column definitions to `columns` and `aoColumns` arrays.

Comment: it is pre-determined and I have 40 columns in total.

Comment: please see above code I added some more code in above question code which I was doing by loop but thatis not suitable for date column.